# End of line Continuation issue

Tags: pine-script

I am trying to resolve the issue with some Pine code but can't seem to find the root cause.
Can anyone kindly assist in finding the cause of the error?

```
indicator(title="Multiple alert criteria - example 1", overlay=false)

rsiValue = ta.rsi(close, 12)

// Set up alert
alertcondition (condition= (rsiValue > 50) and (close > ta.ema(close, 25)),message="RSI > 50 with EMA uptrend")

// Plot values
plot (series=rsiValue,color red,linewidth=2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Change line

```
plot (series=rsiValue,color red,linewidth=2)
```

with

```
plot(rsiValue, color = color.red, linewidth = 2)
```

Comment: Hi. Just going on from this, I am trying to code an alert whereby I get a cross up of the Slow Stochastics K above its signal line D. Along with this, combining the alert so that it only triggers if price is above the 50period SMA. Is this some code you have to hand you can provide? I use to code in tradestation but find Pine a new world!

Comment: alertCondition = close > ta.sma(close, 50) 

if alertCondition

    alert("")